# Sending and Receiving hidden SMS in iOS Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, sms, hidden

Is it possible to send and receive hidden SMS in our app in iOS in Xamarin?
SMS should not alert user through popup rather it should automatically receive in our app like normal message receiving app.Right now not requiring the implementation, just want to know the possibility.

Ali

Comment: You can achieve this with push notification but not with SMS

Answer (score 3):

No, this is **not** something that Apple allows for any application (irrespective of the language/toolkit being used) as it has serious privacy issues.